# PHP - Select sql from html checkbox

Tags: php, html, sql, select, checkbox

I have an html form, with some checkbox.
[image: My form with 4 checkbox]

I want to write an sql to include my checkbox.

For example on my Database: 
Column: **Stato** 
Options: **0,1,2,3** 
 Where:

- 0 = Aperto,
- 1 = Stampato,
- 2 = Bloccato,
- 3 = ❤ (Favorite),

So, if they are all selected you must show me all kinds, otherwise not.

How can I write sql?

**This is my checkbox:**

```
<div id="radioset">
        <input type="checkbox" id="radio1" name="aperto" checked="checked"><label for="radio1">Aperto</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="radio2" name="stampato" checked="checked"><label for="radio2">Stampato</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="radio3" name="bloccato" checked="checked"><label for="radio3">Bloccato</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="radio4" name="favorite" checked="checked"><label for="radio4">&#9829</label>
</div>
```

And this is my PHP sql:

```
$input=$_POST['input'];
$id=$_POST['id'];
$tipo=$_POST['tipo'];
$numero1=$_POST['numero1'];
$numero2=$_POST['numero2'];
$data1=date('d/m/Y', strtotime($_POST['from']));;
$data2=date('d/m/Y', strtotime($_POST['to']));;

$sql="SELECT [Id Ord] AS [ID], [Tipo Ord] AS [Tipo], [N Ord] AS [Numero], [Data Ord] AS [Data], [Ragione Sociale], [Indirizzo], [TotImp] AS [IMPORTO TOTALE], [TotIva] AS [IMPORTO IVA] FROM [Ordini] WHERE [Id Ord] LIKE '$id' OR [Tipo Ord] LIKE '$tipo' OR [Data Ord] BETWEEN #$data1# AND #$data2#";

$rs = $con->execute($sql);
```

Thanks!

Comment: @AnilMaurya I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, define your checkboxes as an array (don't use the terminology "radio" - radio buttons are quite different!), and change the values so they match the database records:

```
<div id="checkboxes">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="options[]" value="0" checked="checked"><label for="checkbox1">Aperto</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="options[]" value="1" checked="checked"><label for="checkbox2">Stampato</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" name="options[]" value="2" checked="checked"><label for="checkbox3">Bloccato</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" name="options[]" value="3" checked="checked"><label for="checkbox4">&#9829</label>
</div>
```

Then you can use a for each loop to loop through them, and if the option is present (checkboxes values don't even exist in the postback if the box wasn't checked) then add a bit of SQL to include that option in the search:

```
$optionsSQL = "";

foreach($_POST["options"] as $index => $option) {
  if ($optionsSQL == "") $optionsSQL = "AND Stato IN ("; //if it's the first detected option, add the IN clause to the string
  $optionsSQL .= $option.",";
}

//trim the trailing comma and add the closing bracket of the IN clause instead
if ($optionsSQL != "") 
{
  $optionsSQL = rtrim($optionsSQL, ","); 
  $optionsSQL .= ")";
}
```

Then lastly, append the `$optionsSQL` string to your query:

```
$sql="SELECT [Id Ord] AS [ID], [Tipo Ord] AS [Tipo], [N Ord] AS [Numero], [Data Ord] AS [Data], [Ragione Sociale], [Indirizzo], [TotImp] AS [IMPORTO TOTALE], [TotIva] AS [IMPORTO IVA] FROM [Ordini] WHERE ([Id Ord] LIKE '$id' OR [Tipo Ord] LIKE '$tipo' OR ([Data Ord] BETWEEN #$data1# AND #$data2#))".$optionsSQL;
```

N.B. Since this is a quick example I have not taken steps here to guard against SQL injection. You should look into how to guard against this - a malicious user could tamper with the option values and try to submit problematic data. You should validate each option value before you use it in a SQL statement.

Comment: Fist thing: I use "radio1" [...] because  it belongs to a jQuery style, If I get it off, I lose the style. Can  keep it without problems?

Comment: yes you can keep it, it's just semantically wrong because radio buttons are something else. I didn't know you were trying to link it to a pre-existing stylesheet. You can change that back without affecting the PHP.

Comment: Great. And how can I turn `"Aperto", "Stampato", "Bloccato", "Favorite"` into `"0","1","2","3"`? Because, in my database "Stato" are "0","1","2","3".

Comment: I already explained that I had fixed that - look at the code. The "value" of each checkbox is now a number instead of a name. I mentioned I had "change the values so they match the database records".

Comment: Yes, you're right. And why have I to use `AND Stato IN`?
I think that should I use `AND` instead of `OR` in all SQL, true? 
Instead, for what is `IN`?

Comment: IN is like a substitute for lots of OR statements. So if the user selected options 1 and 3, then the SQL would effectively say "WHERE...xyz...AND (Stato = 1 OR Stato = 3)". Depends if that's what you want. If you want it to be "AND Stato = 1 AND Stato = 3)" then you'd have to rewrite it a bit, but I'm not sure that makes sense because a column can't have two different values in one row at the same time :-)

Comment: Okay, I try the code, but don't work. `[Microsoft] [ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query.` (I managed to trace the query that writes) --> `'[Indirizzo] LIKE '%tt%' OR [Ragione Sociale] LIKE '%tt%' OR [Id Ord] LIKE '' OR [Tipo Ord] LIKE 'Tutti i tipi' OR [Data Ord] BETWEEN #03/01/2011# AND #11/02/2014#2)'` The last number is sometimes 2 to 3 times, although always changes every time and I select every time all checkbox

Comment: small typo which I've fixed, next line under the foreach should start `if ($optionsSQL == "")` (== instead of =)

Comment: Yes, now nothing error :) But if I select `Tipo: "FP"` and only `Check "Bloccato" (2)`. Table show me also `"1" (Aperto)` Form: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhSZM.png - Table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/APzYO.png ... (This problem is with all colums.. If I select `Tipo = "C1"` and `Data between 2011 and 2014`; The table show me also record with `Tipo = C1 and Data = 2008` or `Tipo = FP and Data = 2013`) ...

Comment: show me the generated entire SQL statement for your first example ( select Tipo: "FP" and only Check "Bloccato" (2))

Comment: How can I do to write the sql on Html? `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
echo $row['fieldname'];
}`

Comment: not the results, the statement :-) `var_dump($sql);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127640/discussion-between-marco-bagiacchi-and-adyson).

Comment: `while($row = mysql_fetch_array(var_dump($sql);)) { 
echo $row['fieldname']; 
}`
? :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a array of checkboxes,

```
<div id="radioset">
  <input type="checkbox" id="radio1" name="options[]" value="aperto" checked="checked"><label for="radio1">Aperto</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="radio2" name="options[]" value="stampato" checked="checked"><label for="radio2">Stampato</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="radio3" name="options[]" value="bloccato" checked="checked"><label for="radio3">Bloccato</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="radio4" name="options[]" value="favorite" checked="checked"><label for="radio4">&#9829</label>
</div>
```

with a name [] you will get a multidimensional ARRAY like $_POST["options"] = array();

When you submit you can do this to get the values,

```
foreach($_POST["options"] AS $index => $option) {
  // example of print all checked boxes
  print $option;

}
```

Tell me if you need any help

Comment: So, at this point, `$option`, has as a value "aperto" or "stampato" or "bloccato" or "favorite". True?

Comment: And how can I turn them into "0","1","2","3"? Because, in my database, I 0,1,2,3.

Comment: @MarcoBagiacchi you can change the value to 0, 1, 2, 3.
The value can be what u want, and can use the label to put the text value for user interpretation.